# Open a obj file in android

Tags: android, cordova, 3d, rotation

I am a PHP programmer and trying phonegap + HTML and android

I had a requirement from client that a android application.
 In which they need to rotate a obj file ( static ) as in 3d applications like maya and then capture its screen shot and save it as a file in that application.

I would likes to try this application myself. I heard about min3d .

Can I meet my requirement with min3d ? or is there any other application ( simple ) for this requirement ?

Please help